# centos - how to find a filename with all the possible extensions?

Tags: regex, find

I need to perform a search for "foo" and return all the filenames/directories with this name (e.g. `foo.php`, `foo.txt` etc). It should run through the whole filesystem and find even hidden files.
 I've tried `find / -name 'foo'` but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find`'s `-name` operator uses shell-style wildcards, so

```
find / -name 'foo.*' -o -name '.foo.*'
```

would find foo.php foo.txt or hidden files like .foo.php etc.  `-o` means "Or", without it a file would have to have both names.  Use `-iname` if you want case insensitive matching.

Comment: cept that isn't going to find hidden files

Comment: ohh stupid me ... it was so easy

Answer (score 0):

use [-regex](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) option which is applied to the full path of each file / dir / socket etc tested

```
find / -regex '.*foo\.(php|txt|iso)'
```

should work for hidden files too.